# Is it bad practice to set HTML tags in React rendering to null?

Tags: reactjs

I found this code example in the ReactJS documentation on how to conditionally set the ID tag on an HTML element.  It sets the value of the ID tag to null if the condition is false.  Is this a bad thing?  Is there a way in ReactJS to just not put any ID tag at all if a condition is not met?

```
ReactDOM.render(<div id={condition ? 'msg' : null}>Hello World!</div>, mountNode);
```

Comment: "It sets the value of the ID tag to null if the condition is false" Which version? https://jsfiddle.net/tb8pz97w/

Comment: And I think you mean "ID attribute" not "ID tag".

Comment: Yes, I meant "attribute"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way in ReactJS to just not put any ID tag at all if a
>   condition is not met?

But that's what this code does:

```
ReactDOM.render(<div id={condition ? 'msg' : null}>Hello World!</div>, mountNode);
```

If condition is falsy, the `id` attribute is omitted as expected:

```
<div data-reactid=".0">Hello World!</div>
```

If truthy:

```
<div id="msg" data-reactid=".0">Hello World!</div>
```

Comment: Ok, just checking to make sure null was ok.  What's the ".0" all about?

Comment: Good question. React uses its own internal ids when performing the differential against the virtual DOM. Basically, we can ignore these, they are used by the internals of React.

Answer (score -1):

Sure you can, element props or attributes can be build like this

```
  render() {

    const props = {
      id: 'myId',
      className: 'myClass'
    }

    return (
        <div {...props}>Hello</div>
    )

  }
```

Then you can add some conditions to set properties

```
if (withTitle) {
  props.title = 'myTitle'
}
```